# How to format the date and time?

Tags: android, kotlin, date

I'm writing a "Feed of posts" application on Kotlin. I faced with such a problem:
The server sends the date and time of the post creation in such a format:

```
"2022-07-13T07:58:57.835201Z"
```

But I need something like this:

```
"13.07.2022 07:58"
```

I've tried something like this:

```kotlin
val pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy"
val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat(pattern)
val newDate = simpleDateFormat.format("2022-07-13T07:58:57.835201Z")
```

But when I do so, I get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`.

Can you please tell me how can I get the desired result?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you know `java.time` and can you use it?

Comment: @deHaar I've tried something like this:
val pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy" 
val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat(pattern) 
val newDate = simpleDateFormat.format("2022-07-13T07:58:57.835201Z")

But when I do so, I get java.lang.IllegalArgumentException.

No, I have never heard about java.time before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use `java.time` (introduced with Java 8), you can simply parse the input `String` to an `OffsetDateTime`, define a `DateTimeFormatter` for your desired output format and then apply it.

Here's how:

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    // your example String
    val input = "2022-07-13T07:58:57.835201Z"
    // parse it to an OffsetDateTime
    val odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(input)
    // create the desired result String by applying the desired format
    val output = odt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.uuuu HH:mm"))
    // print it
    println(output)
}
```

Output:

```
13.07.2022 07:58
```

Comment: You're welcome… Please consider adding an own effort to your next questions.